# How to calculate the correlation of all features with the target variable (binary classifier, python 3)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to calculate in python the correlation of all my features (all of float type) and the **class label** (Binary, 0 or 1). In addition, I would like to plot the data to visualize their distribution by class.

This is needed so I can find features coupled to a single label and find out their real importance. Note that I don't want the pairwise feature correlation and that my classifier is binary.

I have tried the following (from a similar post in stackoverflow) but it is not exactly what I am looking for.

```
df.drop("Target", axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.corr(df.Target))
```

Please see in the picture attached how the distribution would look like for one the features (from Weka).

**Class distribution for one of the features**
[image: Class distribution for one of the features]

Any feedback is really appreciated.

Comment: Just use a `df.corr()` to obatin co-relation between all features, and then drop all the columns except target.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Correlation is not supposed to be used for categorical variables. For more explanation see [here](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-use-Pearsons-correlation-with-categorical-variables)

You can understand the relationship between your independent variables and target variables with the following approach.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
data  = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=False)

import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(data.data[:,:5])
df.columns = data.feature_names[:5]

df['target'] = data.target.astype(str)

import seaborn as sns;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
g= sns.pairplot(df,hue = 'target', diag_kind= 'hist',
             vars=df.columns[:-1],
             plot_kws=dict(alpha=0.5), 
             diag_kws=dict(alpha=0.5))
plt.show()
```

[image]